# Apply sed operations only to lines beginning with a particular string

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have the following file format

```
Received from +11231231234 at 2021-10-10T19:56:50-07:00:
This is a message that contains words like from, at, etc.

Sent to +11231231234 at 2021-10-11T06:50:57+00:00:
This is another message that contains words like to, at, etc.
```

I want to clean up the "Received" and "Sent" lines, the following sed commands achieves this

```
cat file |  sed 's/from//g' | sed 's/to/    /g' | sed 's/+\w\+//' | \ 
sed 's/at//g' | sed 's/T/ /g' | sed 's/[[:digit:].]*\:$//' | \ 
sed 's/[[:digit:].]*\:$//' | sed 's/-$//' | sed 's/-$//' | sed 's/+$//'
```

and results in the following

```
Received    2021-10-10 19:56:50
This is a message that contains words like  ,  , etc.

Sent        2021-10-11 06:50:57
This is another message that contains words like  ,  , etc.
```

As you can see it does clean up the "Received" and "Sent" lines nicely. But it also cleans up the message lines! How can I apply these operations only on lines starting with "Received" and "Sent" ?

Comment: Crossposted to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/679965/13792)

Answer (score 6):

You can use a pattern to pick out which lines to apply a subsequent command to:

```
sed '/^Sent\|^Received/ s/pattern/replacement/' your_file
```

### Bonus

You can actually do all of your edits in one glorious sed command:

```
sed '/^Received\|^Sent/ s/\(^[^ ]*\).*at \(.*\)T\(.*\)[-+].*/\1 \2 \3/' your_file
```

Essentially, the pattern matches every piece of text on the line and we just
'remember' all the bits we want to keep, and then replace the entire line with
them.

Output:

```
Received 2021-10-10 19:56:50
This is a message that contains words like from, at, etc.

Sent 2021-10-11 06:50:57
This is another message that contains words like to, at, etc.
```

The way it works is as follows:

- `\(` and `\)` are 'capture groups' that remember whatever was matched in
  between them.
- `^[^ ]*` matches the beginning of a line followed by any number of
  consecutive non-whitespace characters (i.e. the first word on the line).
- `.*at`  matches everything up to and including the word 'at' (and the space
  following it) - this is not in a capture group and so is not 'remembered'.
- `\(.*\)T` remembers (in the second capture group) everything up to, but not
  including the capital 'T'.
- `\(.*\)[-+].*` remembers (in the third capture group) everything up to, but
  not including, either a '-' or a '+' (and anything that follows the '-/+').
- `/\1 \2 \3/` means replace the match (i.e. the entire line) with the
  contents of the 1st, 2nd and 3rd capture groups.

[This page](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) explains sed very well -
also it has a fantastic set of [other unix
tutorials](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/index.html).

Comment: thank you sexy  man